# UIBezierPath Draw line while touchesMoved with two fingers

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

How can I draw a line in touchesMoved using UIBezierPath? When I am trying to draw a line using two touches/fingers, it is being drawn but it draws multiple lines. I tried removing lastObjectIndex and also tried removeAllObjects but still the same result. I would just like to draw a single line from finger 1 to finger 2 and when the user releases his/her finger then the line will be drawn on a UIImageView. Here is my code:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ([drawMode isEqualToString:@"stroke"]) {
        UITouch *touch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
        [myPath addLineToPoint:[touch locationInView:self]];
    }
    else if ([drawMode isEqualToString:@"line"]) {
        NSArray *allTouches = [touches allObjects];
        if ([touches count] == 2) {
            UITouch *touch1 = [allTouches objectAtIndex:0];
            UITouch *touch2 = [allTouches objectAtIndex:1];
            CGPoint touchLoc1 = [touch1 locationInView:self];
            CGPoint touchLoc2 = [touch2 locationInView:self];
            [myPath moveToPoint:touchLoc1];
            [myPath addLineToPoint:touchLoc2];
            [shapeArray removeAllObjects];
            [shapeArray addObject:myPath];
        }
    }

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: Talk is cheap... Show some code so we can help.

Comment: I've already added some code. I was thinking of an alternative to use Quartz 2D / CGContextAddLineToPoint to draw but nothing appears on my app. Maybe because I am using a custom UIView?